# How do you include tests from a lib directory in Rails rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you include tests that are in a lib folder in your rake tasks?

For example, you have a foo library you are building in the `/lib/foo` directory of your Rails project and would like to keep all of your foo tests in the `lib/foo/tests` directory.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to consolidate from all the different sources, so I wanted to post here for anyone looking!

This imports the rake file from my `lib/foo/test` directory:

```
# Rakefile:

Dir.glob('lib/foo/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| load r}
```

This adds the `test:foo_tests` task to my rake tasks:

```
# lib/foo/tasks/test.rake

require "rake/testtask"
namespace :test do
  Rake::TestTask.new(foo_tests: 'test:prepare') do |t|
    t.pattern = 'lib/foo/test/**/*_test.rb'
  end
end
```

I hope this helps someone else!